# Problems publishing Silverlight/Blend video player

Tags: silverlight, video, xap

Sticking my toe into the Silverlight/Blend pool, I've worked through some very cool video tutorials. My video player project runs and works as expected when I build the project within Blend 4 and when I insert the video media (.xap) into the webpage and preview it from within Expression Web.
All great. But when I publish the page and assets, the player doesn't show up.

[Video Player page](http://dongarber.com/silverlight/videoplayer1/index.html)

Anyone have any ideas on what's missing...? Maybe what I fouled up on?
I published all the files to my server just as they're in my working folders...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is getting a HTTP 404 error when attempting to load the XAP file. The XAP file is either missing or the path to the XAP is incorrect. The URI the page is using to load the XAP is `http://dongarber.com/silverlight/videoplayer1/silverlight/VideoPlayer.xap` The source parameter is pointing to a location relative to the page.

```
     <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="640" height="480">
                     <param name="source" value="silverlight/VideoPlayer.xap"/>
                     <param name="background" value="white" />
                     <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" />
                     <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none;"/>
        </a>
                 </object>
```

Comment: Good gracious, Dave, you're right. It's VideoPlayer.xap in the web file as shown above, but it was named videoplayer.xap (no caps) as uploaded... It's always the little things, isnt' it?! Thanks very much. I need to buy a more powerful magnifying (debugging) glass!! :-)